# Очень долго загружаются контакты из телефона

Tags: java, android

```
public static List<PhoneModel> getContactPhones(ContentResolver contentResolver){
        List<PhoneModel> listPhone=new ArrayList<>();

        String projectPhone[]={ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID};
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projectPhone, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String family="";

            String whereData= ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+"=?";
            String projecData[]={ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME};
            Cursor cursorFamily=contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,projecData,
                    whereData, new String[]{id}, null);
            String strTemp="";
            if (cursorFamily!=null){
                cursorFamily.moveToFirst();
                strTemp=cursorFamily.getString(cursorFamily.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
                if (strTemp!=null){
                    family=strTemp;
                }
                cursorFamily.close();
            }

            ....add Array List.....
        }
        cursor.close();

        return listPhone;
    }
```

У меня в телефонной книге 10 тыс контактов. Запуск данного кода занимает от 15 - 20 сек. По идее ну максимум 3 сек должно быть. А тут такое

Это же не нормально? Я понимаю что, я что - то упустил в ContentProvider. Прошу помочь. Мучаюсь уже 4 день.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понимаю, вы этот код выполняете в главном потоке, который и так нагружен задачами, попробуйте выполнить этот код с использованием класса Thread